# ArrayList multi sort with Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, queue

I am completely confused, I have been attempting to do this multi way sort and cannot get the first iteration through to work.  I have tried and changed multiple things multiple times changing String[] and ArrayLists but cannot figure it out.  I have searched here and cannot find a solution that makes sense.

The goal is to pull from a file sort by vowel count and then sort by word length.

Get the file which works fine...

```
private static String[] getFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    String homedir = System.getProperty("user.home");
    System.out.print("homedir = " + homedir);
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(new File(homedir));
    jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
    File file = jfc.getSelectedFile();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    System.out.println("File read = " + file);
    ArrayList <String> initialList = copyWords(scanner);
    return initialList;
}
```

This also works fine, but I assume the problem might be in here that I need to change the input to the correct type before it is added???

```
private static ArrayList copyWords(Scanner scanner) {
    ArrayList<String> initialList = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Words in the file = ");  
    int count =0;
    while (scanner.hasNext()){
        //String word = scanner.next().toLowerCase();
        initialList.add(scanner.next().toLowerCase());
    }
        for (String word : initialList)
        System.out.print(word + "    ");
            count++;
        if (count == 10) { 
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    return initialList;
}
```

Not entirely done yet, it does pull the amount of vowels correctly or assumed correctly.  Creating a number of queues equal to the highest number of vowels plus one more for those with zero.

```
private static String[] sortByVowelCount(ArrayList<String> initialList) {
    ArrayList<String> queues = createQueues(getNumberOfQueues(initialList) +1);
    fillAndPrint(initialList, queues);
    return clear(queues);
    }

private static int getNumberOfQueues(ArrayList<String> initialList) {
    int highVowelCount = 0;
    for (String word : initialList) {
        int numberOfVowels = vowelCount(word);
        if (numberOfVowels>highVowelCount)
            highVowelCount = numberOfVowels;
    }
    System.out.println(highVowelCount);
    return highVowelCount;
}

private static int vowelCount(String word) {
    int vowelCount = 0;
     for (char c : word.toCharArray())
         if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u')
             vowelCount++;
     return vowelCount;    
}
```

This part was recently changed I know this is now not accurate.  The .add is my issue.  I am having problems adding it back, I have tried to change the variable that I am using and different types but to no avail.

```
private static ArrayList<String> createQueues(int total) {
    ArrayList<String> queues = new ArrayList(total);
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i ++)
    return queues;
}

  private static void fillAndPrint(String[] initialList, ArrayList queues) {
    int count = 0;
    String[] fill = new String[1];
    for (String word : initialList)
        fill[1] = word;
        queues.get(getNumberOfQueues(fill)).add(fill);
    printQueue(queues);
    }
```

Comment: I know that up until the max vowel works as all prints until there do as they are supposed to.  It is only after here that there is an issue; in the actual adding to the new queues and then printing the first sort out.

Comment: In your `createQueues(int total)` method, what is the purpose of that `for` loop? Also, have you tried to debug your program to see what is wrong?

Comment: To return the amount of queues needed to store the words by vowel amount.  I must have deleted that last line prior it was simply to create the queues `queues.add(new LinkedList<>());`

Comment: Debug stops at this line here `queues.get(getNumberOfQueues(fill)).add(fill);` it is in the `fillAndPrint` method.

Comment: `queues` is an arraylist that can hold `Strings` only. How come you can do this:  `queues.add(new LinkedList<>());`? Also, `queues.get(getNumberOfQueues(fill)).add(fill);` will give you compilation error too. Because `queues.get(...)` will return you a `String` and on that string you are doing `string.add(...)`. String class doesn't have any add method. Please add your full stack trace.

Comment: Its presumed that it is entirely a mess now because I have just been changing bits and pieces of the code for the last two days attempting to solve the problem, through searches here and on google.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: textprocessing.MultiSort.clear
 at textprocessing.MultiSort.sortByVowelCount(MultiSort.java:66)
 at textprocessing.MultiSort.main(MultiSort.java:29)
[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]/Users/jackschirtz/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 11 seconds)`

Comment: Thats after another change though so now that stops at the `clear` method that has not been done yet. Here is the stack with the clear removed.. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: <any>.add
 at textprocessing.MultiSort.fillAndPrint(MultiSort.java:103)
 at textprocessing.MultiSort.sortByVowelCount(MultiSort.java:65)
 at textprocessing.MultiSort.main(MultiSort.java:29)
/Users/jackschirtz/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 14 seconds)`

Comment: To be honest I am about ready to wipe it and just start over.  I feel like I have just utterly confused myself by going through and changing things over and over again.  I feel lost, I am not even sure at some points what has maintained and what has been changed automatically by netbeans error help.

Comment: Give your methods and variables meaningful names. You have defined `queues` as an Arraylist. The method `getNumberOfQueues( )` returns `highestVowelCount`. Make your code more readable. Good luck

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to give it a go again tonight I may be back haha